Enumitem inline list: top margin
How to increase the vertical gap above an enumitem inline list? I tried topsep but it had no effect.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newlist{mc}{enumerate*}{1}%
\setlist[mc]{
    topsep=3ex,
    label=(\Alph*),
    itemjoin={\hspace{1em}}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\kant[1][1]
\begin{mc}
    \item test
    \item test
    \item test
    \item test
\end{mc}
\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


Please clarify what you mean by "manage". E.g., do you want to increase or decrease the vertical gaps?

your question is strangely worded, as inline lists are inline so they have no vertical offset,  there is no top margin to increase or decrease. Your use of \kant obscures it but it is \kant that is ending the paragraph not the \begin{mc} starting one, trey putting abc after \kant[1][1]  so if you are asking to have a space before the paragraph containing that list, use \bigskip before the \begin

Inline lists are inline they have no vertical spacing. Your example has no blank line before the \begin{mc} but there is one implicitly added by the \kant macro that starts a new paragraph as you can more easily see if you add additional text:
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newlist{mc}{enumerate*}{1}%
\setlist[mc]{
    topsep=3ex,
    label=(\Alph*),
    itemjoin={\hspace{1em}}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\kant[1][1] www
\begin{mc}
    \item test
    \item test
    \item test
    \item test
\end{mc}
    xxx
\begin{mc}
    \item test
    \item test
    \item test
    \item test
\end{mc}
    yyy.
    
\end{document}


So (I think) your question is asking how to add some vertical space before the paragraph that contains the list, you could use any standard command such as \bigskip but here I use quoation you coudl define a custom enviornment that defined such an offset paragraph containing an inline list rather than nesting each time:
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newlist{mc}{enumerate*}{1}%
\setlist[mc]{
    topsep=3ex,
    label=(\Alph*),
    itemjoin={\hspace{1em}}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\kant[1][1] www
\begin{quotation}
\begin{mc}
    \item test
    \item test
    \item test
    \item test
\end{mc}
\end{quotation}
xxx
\begin{quotation}
  \begin{mc}
    \item test
    \item test
    \item test
    \item test
\end{mc}
\end{quotation}
    yyy.
  

  
\end{document}



If I understand correctly what you want, according to the image you have shown and assuming that mc means multiple choice, I think that the enumext package can do the job:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumext}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\setenumext[keyans*]{topsep=3ex,label=(\Alph*),columns=4,columns-sep=1em}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumext}[save-ans=test,nosep,show-ans=true]
\item \kant[1][1]
\begin{keyans*}
    \item* test
    \item test
    \item test
    \item test
\end{keyans*}

\item \kant[1][1]
\begin{keyans*}
    \item test
    \item* test
    \item test
    \item test
\end{keyans*}
\end{enumext}
% print keys
\printkeyans{test}

\end{document}


I recommend reading the package documentation.
